# How to create SPQuery by filtering date interval

Tags: development, event-receivers, filter

I have a custom aspx form where I retrieve list items by filtering two values `EventDate` and `EndDate`. I have a realization but it returns nothing:

```
 DateTime eventDate = Convert.ToDateTime(properties.AfterProperties["EventDate"].ToString());
 DateTime endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(properties.AfterProperties["EndDate"].ToString());

SPSite site = new SPSite("http://local/");
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
SPList list = web.Lists["eRoom"];
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.DatesInUtc = true;
query.Query = String.Format(
   "<Where>" +
        "<And>" +
                "<Geq><FieldRef Name='EventDate'/><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='True'StorageTZ='TRUE'>{0}</Value></Geq>" +
                "<Leq><FieldRef Name='EndDate'/><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='True' StorageTZ='TRUE'>{1}</Value></Leq>" +
        "</And>" +
   "</Where>",
   eventDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"),
   endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")
);

SPListItemCollection itemColl = list.GetItems(query);
```

What is wrong?

Comment: No white space between StorageTZ and 'True' in the <Geq>. Use SPCamlQueryBuilder to debug your CAML query more quickly: https://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Boland the same thing

Comment: @testimon123 Did you find a solution to your problem in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me. You should double check *eventDate* and *endDate* parameter values. I've tested your code with DateTime columns with default values set during creation.

Answer (score 0):

**try with this:**

```
eventDate.ToString("s"),
endDate.ToString("s")
```